# is_dir() returns FALSE when passed a subfolder

Tags: php

is_dir() according to the php manual returns true if passed a string that refers to a folder.
It's returning false -- despite being passed an array of valid folder names -- this is probably something simple but I'm beating myself up over not finding it.

Here is the code:

```
define('TEST_SUBFOLDERS_FILES_PATH', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/theProj/mainSubdir/');

$currentFolder = ' ';
$rootOfmainSubdir = TEST_SUBFOLDERS_FILES_PATH';
$theArrayOfDirsAndFilesInmainSubdir;

// fill an array that contains all files and folders under the /mainSubdir folder
// using php's 'scandir()'
if( ($theArrayOfDirsAndFilesInmainSubdir = scandir($rootOfmainSubdir )) != FALSE )
{
  $numArrayEntries = count($theArrayOfDirsAndFilesInmainSubdir);
  echo "<br><br>The number of folders/files found is:  " . $numArrayEntries;


  // now do the triage on subfolders under /mainSubdir  versus files
  for($i = 0; $i < $numArrayEntries; $i++)
  {
    echo "<br><br>Current array element is:  " 
            . $theArrayOfDirsAndFilesInmainSubdir[$i]
            . "  and is_dir() on this element returns --> "
            . var_dump( is_dir($theArrayOfDirsAndFilesInmainSubdir[$i]) );  
    // rest of code
```

Here is what I see on the output for almost all the folders:

```
Current array element is: testFolderN and is_dir() on this element returns -->

boolean false
```

OR I see:

```
Current array element is: . and is_dir() on this element returns -->

boolean true
```

AND:

```
Current array element is: .. and is_dir() on this element returns -->

boolean true
```

I'm missing something really dumb here but sheesh.  It seems that is_dir() is correctly returning TRUE only for the current folder "." and the parent folder ".."

If there is a nuance I'm missing in the use of is_dir() I'm not seeing it.

Help is appreciated -- all I'm going to do in the code is to make a list of the current subfolders under the TEST_SUBFOLDERS_FILES_PATH if I can get is_dir() to return TRUE not only for "." and ".." but also the other 'testFolderN' subfolders.

By the way -- there is a total of 5 subfolders, and one file in the directory, so the display of the count above is:

```
The number of folders/files found is: 8
```

Comment: Off-topic :- Terrible variable name, too long and hard to understand

Comment: too much code to test just one function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You scan the `$rootOfmainSubdir`, but you test for `is_dir()`ness in your current directory. You can either prepend the root and directory separator before checking, or `chdir()` in there. Note, that your current directory also has `.` and `..` entries.

Comment: Hi everyone, I up-arrowed everyone because you took time to help out a fellow coder.  I'm not into downvotes.  Not sure how long it takes us all to figure out that you can never have to many friends out there.  Good luck to y'all and THANKS MAN!  I have to accept Michael here as he was first but as with other questions a lot of great answers here, thanks for that.  The 'nuance' was not with is_dir() at all -- the 'nuance' is that scandir()'s array lops off the fully-qualified path and I didn't catch that (first time in my life I've used scandir() he said humbly).  HAVE A GREAT WEEKEND DUDES!

Comment: This is valid. Every one makes this mistake. Checking is_dir() without the complete file path

Answer (score 1):

You will have to prepend the `$rootOfmainSubdir` in your call to `is_dir` like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $numArrayEntries; $i++)
{
   echo "<br><br>Current array element is:  " 
        . $theArrayOfDirsAndFilesInmainSubdir[$i]
        . "  and is_dir() on this element returns --> "
        . var_dump( is_dir(rootOfmainSubdir.$theArrayOfDirsAndFilesInmainSubdir[$i]) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace everything with a simple call to `glob`

```
$dirs = glob("C:/xampp/htdocs/theProj/mainSubdir/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

Details :- http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 0):

The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) says that the file name you give `is_dir()` is the

> Path to the file. If filename is a relative filename, it will be checked relative 
>   to the current working directory.

So you need to put "./" before each directory in order for is_dir to search the *current* directory for it. Otherwise, it looks under "/", probably not what you want.

Comment: I used a recursive function to upload files & this hint helps me. thanks @djhaskin987