# PHP is_dir always returns false

Tags: php, linux, sudo, chmod

I am trying to use the is_dir function, but it always returns false even if the directory does indeed exist.
I am a very new Linux user(xubuntu), and i read in similar questions here that the issue is probably the directory permission. I have tried using:

```
sudo chmod -R folder_path
```

But it's still not working.
How can i fix it?
Thanks.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that i am working in codeigniter. I have tried to use file_exists(which like is_dir doesn't work in my codeigniter project) on 2  separate files, and it worked. Is it possible that the problem is because i am using codeigniter?

Comment: try `sudo chmod 777 /folder path -R`

Comment: You're probably not specifying the path correctly. If you're using `readdir`, a common mistake is to forget to concatenate the filename with the directory before calling functions like `is_dir`. Show your code.

Comment: I'll bet your problem is a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370237/is-dir-returns-false-when-passed-a-subfolder?rq=1

Comment: please show owner name for folder

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the problem was. It was the .htaccess that cause the problem, because it was on Deny from all so that cause the problem that i had. I changed it to Allow from all, and now it works well.
Sorry for not explain myself better, but the problem is solved so thank  you very much for your help.

Comment: .htaccess was causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about permissions, use:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 folder_path
```

Also remember that is_dir() function caching the result, from documentation:

```
Note: The results of this function are cached. See clearstatcache() for more details.
```

Maybe this is Your problem?

Or Try to use absolute path instead of relative one.

Comment: No please don't use 777. That makes it writable for _all users_ and is a security risk. If it needs to be writable, you need it to be writable by the web server user, which on an Ubuntu (debian) system is `www-data`. The more appropriate and secure action is to make the directory have that as its group and  be group writable `775`.  `chown :www-data folder_path`

Comment: Why does it need to be writable at all? `is_dir()` doesn't try to change anything.

Comment: @Barmar Indeed.  The thing to check is that the entire tree above this directory is _executable_ by the web server user so it can traverse down to this directory.

Comment: While it's possible that there could be missing execute permissions, this is very rare. I'll bet anything it's a problem in his PHP code.

Comment: i have tried to use sudo chmod -R 775 folder_path, but it's not working either.

Comment: @user3460046 Ok so show Your code. This is related probably to wrong path.

Comment: szymanskilukasz, i don't think it's related to code, i have tried to use file_exists to a file in the same folder but it also returns false. I am using Codeigniter is it possible that this is the problem?

Comment: This is the part from my Codeigniter project:<?php

//is_dir test 
    echo __DIR__ . '<br>';
    var_dump(is_dir('../cache'));
    echo '<br>';
    var_dump(file_exists('order.php')) ;
?>  I have tried now to test file_exists out of my Codeigniter project on 2 php files, and it works! so i think the problem is Codeiginter.

Comment: @user3460046 Try to put abosulte path to is_dir, not relative one.

Comment: @user3460046 So please mark my answer as correct. I've edited it with absolute path suggestion. This behaviour tells You that You were using wrong relative path.